# Manipulating Strings that are inside Text Files

Tags: string, powershell, batch-file, csv

Here's my situation:

We depend on users to click some .bat and do the daily-backup.

I did some batching programming, now when they (are forced to) back-up, it leaves a log file in it's own the server folder. And yes, they need to be forced otherwise they just won't do the g.damn backup... Welcome to my company.

Then, after some more research, I developed another bat which checks if the file is outdated and prints it on a text file.

This is the kind of files that I have now:

**File:** DailyBkp

**Content:**

> ".\John\log.log"
>
> ".\Department1\Andy\log.log"
>
> ".\Department1\Nicole\log.log"
>
> ".\Department2\Ann\log.log"

**File:** Departments

**Content:**

> Department1
>
> Department2
>
> ...

Great, after some string treatment in `PowerShell` I managed to get `DailyBkp` content to be this:

```
John 

Department1 Andy 

...
```

Note that it has a space at beginning and another at the end which won't go away no matter what trim I use...

So now I have this setup: `SERVER > E:\Backup\`

Inside backup we have i.e. `"Department 1" ... "Dep.-N"`

Inside each one: `"User-Lastname1" .. "User-lastname-N"`

What I need, or what I do want to is use PowerShell to get the contents of `DailyBkp` containing `"Dept_User"` string, and export entries to a `csv` file like this:

```
 COLUMN_Name      COLUMN_Dept
 Andy             Department1
```

So, how do I do this? I can't find anything on internet that uses text files.

Comment: You are really solving the wrong problem. Never left backups to the users. Start using version control and server backups to store the data safe.

Comment: I know I'am, but in the real world, as an auxiliary, the only thing I can do is try to help using things that are at my range. Another reason is to learn about powershell.

Answer (score 0):

so assuming I am reading your question correctly you have a DailyBkp file that looks like this:

```
Department1 Andy
Dpeartment2 Jim
...
```

to get what you want you could read each line in split it out then spit it back out in a csv like this:

```
"COLUMN_Name,COLUMN_Dept" | out-file <path>\outfile.csv
$bkpFile = get-content $dailyBkpFile
$bkpFile | ForEach-Object {$line = $_.split(" ")
"$($line[1]),$($line[0])" | out-file <path>\outfile.csv -Append}
```

output should look like this:

```
 COLUMN_Name,COLUMN_Dept
 Andy,Department1
 Jim,Department2
```

Comment: Hi, after some scripting I did managed to get exactly what I wanted. But your version looks better, I`m writing data right into excel and then closing all -Com objects.
If you guys thinks its valid to me sharing what method I used, ask me c:

Answer (score 0):

just doind a quick post here.
My question was answered, thanks.
And, if anyone is interested in Powershell programming, google **Mastering Powershell** by *Tobias Weltner*; this is a free book with lots of explanations.